# Connect DualShock 3 (PS3 controller) and MacBook Pro 13" late 2013 on Mavericks 10.9.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, games

The steps I have taken to connect my dualshock 3 controller with my MBP are shown here: http://theultralinx.com/2014/02/connect-playstation-3-controller-mac-os-mavericks.html

The controller doesn't show up as PS3 Controller in my devices list ever. Just some cryptic hexadecimal numbers flagged with 'not connected'.

Here is a log from when I

-> turned on BT

-> connected the controller via usb

-> disconnected the controller from usb

-> pressed the ps button (at that point the 'enter passcode for ps3 controller'-window comes up, but nothing ever happens thereafter)

```
Mar 28 03:43:52 Otzebook kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xb000 ****
Mar 28 03:43:52 Otzebook coreaudiod[279]: PowerState:1 bluedXPCConnection:0x7f83b07419e0
Mar 28 03:43:52 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar 28 03:43:52 Otzebook blued[11079]: hostControllerOnline - Number of Paired devices = 0, List of Paired devices = (
    )
Mar 28 03:43:52 Otzebook coreaudiod[279]: PowerState:1 bluedXPCConnection:0x7f83b07419e0
Mar 28 03:44:22 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 28 03:44:32 Otzebook kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 1c:7e:e5:95:9f:46
Mar 28 03:44:42 Otzebook blued[11079]: Removing Bluetooth configured device: 00-1e-3d-de-ee-38
Mar 28 03:44:42 Otzebook kernel[0]: [0xffffff80203a5700][free]()
Mar 28 03:44:42 Otzebook kernel[0]: ### ERROR: opCode = 0x0406 (Disconnect) -- send request failed (err=0x0012 (kBluetoothHCIErrorInvalidHCICommandParameters))
Mar 28 03:44:42 Otzebook coreaudiod[279]: XPC method:BTDeviceDisconnected
Mar 28 03:44:42 Otzebook kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 1c:7e:e5:95:9f:46
```

The controller just stops blinking after some time and is still not connected / paired.

Has anyone any idea on why this doesn't work? Or some further ideas on how to debug this problem?

Comment: You need the cable to pair.

Comment: remove the link, describe what you did.

Answer (score 1):

What i did was plug in my PS3 controller with bluetooth settings open then once the controller was plugged in i turned off bluetooth turned it back on and reset the controller, after i reset the controller i pressed the ps button and hey presto it was connected

Comment: Same here. You need the cable to pair.